# PowerShell Scripts to report and alert on site and subsite size

Tags: powershell, statistics, health

Can anyone help me to write PowerShell scripts that do the following:

1. Report and alert on site and subsite size
2. Report and alert on individual file size
3. Collect search statistics

Comment: hi muneyi and welcome to SharePoint overflow. We are glad to have you and will try our best to assist you in solving your problems. The key word here being **assist**. We will try to point you in the right direction, but dont expect us to do all your work for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I take it you got a good reason for doing this in PowerShell -realize that you will only get a warning/report each time you run this script unless you in the script generate event log entries or similar for other monitoring devices.

Also consider using the OOB functionality for Quota and Quota warnings where you get notifications when site collections are getting near quotas.

If you use SharePoint 2010 consider using the Health Monitoring features. Besides the OOB rules and health checks you can define your own rules. You can get output as logs or reports.

Check out the Monitoring section of SharePoint 2010 on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748636.aspx) for an overview on what you can monitor.